# Cordova file plugin - save file in device

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova, cordova-plugin-file

I'm having a lot of troubles saving files in Android.
The project is a hybrid application developed with Ionic with these plugins:

```
com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener 1.0.0 "File Opener"
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.4.2 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.0.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.2-dev "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.3-dev "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.0.4-dev "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Android platform version is `5.2.1`
The device I'm using is a `Samsung A7`

This is an abstract from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

## Case1

if I try with this snippet (actually working on another project)

```js
var storagePath = "/storage/emulated/0";
var fileDir = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, '');
var fileName = $scope.ngDocument.documentId + ".pdf"
var filePath = storagePath + "/" + fileDir + fileName;
$cordovaFile.writeFile(filePath, BINARY_ARR, {'append': false}).then(function(result) {}, function(err) {});
```

I get `{"code":5,"message":"ENCODING_ERR"}` as Callback from the `$cordovaFile.writeFile`, no matter if I use absolute path, relative path, just the file name and no file is ever created.

## Case2

With this snippet

```js
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
  console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
  fs.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
    console.log("fileEntry:" + JSON.stringify(fileEntry));
    writeFile(fileEntry, BINARY_ARR);
  }, function(data){});
}, function(data){});
```

happen two different things

### Case 2.1

If no config options are specified in `config.xml` the app creates an empty folder into /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/{myAPP}

### Case 2.2

with these two preferences

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="cache" />
```

a file in `/storage/emulated/0` (external SSD) is created and in `logcat`errors are:

```
E/Vold    ( 2280): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/{myApp}/files/
W/Vold    ( 2280): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 0
W/ContextImpl(13364): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/{myApp}/files
E/Vold    ( 2280): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/{myApp}/files/
W/Vold    ( 2280): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 0
W/ContextImpl(13364): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/{myApp}/files
E/Vold    ( 2280): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/{myApp}/cache/
W/Vold    ( 2280): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 0
W/ContextImpl(13364): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/{myApp}/cache
```

The strange fact is that `/storage/extSdCard` (symbolic link for `/mnt/extSdCard`) is not mounted while the external SSD is mounted on `/mnt/sdcard`

Please help: I'm headbanging.
The first snippet was working as a charm in another project. Could it be the version of ngCordova?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## SOLVED:

after several attempts I solved in this way

in `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,cache, sdcard, cache-external, files-external" />
```

and main function:

```js
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

    //var absPath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/";
    var absPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
    var fileDir = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, '');
    var fileName = "somename.txt";
    var filePath = fileDir + fileName;

    fs.root.getFile(filePath, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        writeFile(fileEntry, BINARY_ARR).then(function(){
          //do something here
        });
    }, function(err) {});
}, function(err) {});

function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function () {
                resolve();
            };
            fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                reject(e);
            };
            fileWriter.write(dataObj);
        });
    });
}
```

It seemed that:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
```

that is the default configuration, could not allow the app to write into the external disk (whether physical or emulated). Instead allowed the app only to write into `/data/data/{myApp}/files`

Comment: Hi I am trying to save a xml file to device using your code but i am confusing with where to pass the data

Comment: Data is the BINARY_ARR variabile .. as the name suggests it must be a binary array

Comment: When I try your code, I'm getting an error named writefile.then is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is the whole explain of how to save the file. Using file plugin cordova:

Suppose you have to Save a file with text *"Hello Mr. Vaibhav Mojidra"* in a **.txt** inside internal storage.

so here it goes if you have button click  in HTML like this:
Now inside SaveFile function:

```
       var textt="";
       function SaveFile(text)
      {
         textt=text; /* initialize global variable with text to be written in file */
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

         /* This will check permission for storage read and write, and if got permission then 
          function send parameter will be called else if not granted then third parameter ie 
         fail function will be called */
      }

      function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) 
      {
         fileSystem.root.getFile("Demo.txt",{create: true, exclusive: 
      false},gotFileEntry,fail);
        /* This will create a file with name Demo.txt in internal storage . and similarly on 
         sucessfully create it will call second parameter function i.e. gotFileEntry */
      }

      function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        /* This will get a file object with path call createWriter in which 1st parameter is 
       use to write content in file and second parameter of fail to create writer */
      }

      function gotFileWriter(writer) 
      {
         writer.write(textt);/* passing parameter of the textt which is global and initialize 
       at first called function*/
          writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            alert("File Saved");
          }; /*This function will be called once file is written with text and saved */
       }

     function fail(error)
     {
       alert("Error","There was some problem\nError:"+error.code,"Ok");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function to write and create new folder

```
function writeFile(path, filename, blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (dirpar) {
            dirpar.getDirectory(path, { create: true }, function (dir) {
                dir.getFile(filename, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                        fileWriter.onwriteend = resolve
                        fileWriter.onerror = reject
                        fileWriter.write(blob);
                    });
                }, reject);
            }, reject);
        }, reject);
    });
}
```

how to call function

```
writeFile("AppFolder", 'file.name', blob)
```

sample download an image and save in folder

```
var url = "image url"

fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {

    writeFile("pictures/myapp", url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), blob)
        .then(function () { console.log("file donwloaded.") })
        .catch(function (e) { console.error("error:", e) })

});
```

Answer (score -3):

use FileTransfer plugin : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer for downloads and https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-pdialog to show the Progress Dialog.

```
function saveFileDownloaded(url, nameFile) {
    var uri = url;
    var test = isEncoded(url)
    if (test == false) {
        uri = encodeURI(url)
    }
    var fileTransfer = new window.FileTransfer();
    var fileURL = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "Direct/" + nameFile;
     cordova.plugin.pDialog.init({
                    theme : 'DEVICE_LIGHT',
                    progressStyle : 'HORIZONTAL',
                    cancelable : false,
                    message : 'Téléchargement en cours...'
                });
    fileTransfer.onprogress = function(result) {
        var percent = result.loaded / result.total * 100;
        percent = Math.round(percent);   
         cordova.plugin.pDialog.setProgress(percent);       
    };
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        fileURL,
        function(entry) {
            cordova.plugin.pDialog.dismiss();
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                'Voulez vous ouvrir le fichier', // message
                function(buttonIndex) {
                    onConfirm(buttonIndex, fileURL);
                }, // callback to invoke
                'Téléchargement terminé', // title
                ['Ok', 'Exit'] // buttonLabels
            );
        },
        function(error) {
                    cordova.plugin.pDialog.dismiss();
            console.log(error)
            alert("Erreur lors du téléchargement, vérifier votre connexion!");
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: why should I use FileUpload when I just need to create a new file?

Comment: when you should use FileUpload ?

Comment: thanks for the answer and for the support. However it's OFFTOPIC. I will not downvote even though I should have to.

Comment: file transfer plugin now deprecated and dose not support android 10+